# sending session cookie with each subsequent HTTP request in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, session, cookies

I am trying to communicate to a RESTFul API using MATLAB. the API uses session cookie to remember the user. My MATALB is 2015b and as long as I know, it does not support the new [HTTP Interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-wsdl-web-services_bu9hx2b-1.html).

my problem is that using the `webread` and `webwrite` functions in MATLAB, the session cookie is not attached to the request and therefore each time server generates a new session.

I tried to use [urlread2](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/expanding-urlreads-capabilities/) to read the session cookie and generate a new one with the same content, for sending back to the server, but the session cookie is HTTPOnly and therefore my generated cookie is not valid for the server.

Can anyone help me with an idea or solution? does MATLAB 2016b forward the session cookie automatically (using HTTP interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to this problem:

first problem is to get the cookie info in MATLAB. versions earlier than 2016b are probably not able to do it, so I had to use  for it:

```
[output,extras] = urlread2('http://www.example.com/','GET');
cookie = extras.firstHeaders.Set_Cookie;  % make sure to get the content of the right session cookie
```

now that we have the cookie, let's add it to the |weboptions| like this:

```
opts = weboptions('KeyName','Cookie','KeyValue',cookie);
```

and now simply every time that you use |webread| or |webwrite| , attach the |opts| to it:

```
response = webread('http://www.example.com/',opts);
```

But using this method, it is very easy to do XSS attacks on websites that use HTTPOnly cookies for session management! unlike all the web browsers, matlab allows you to edit or create HTTPOnly cookies! [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150304/matlab-allows-creating-editing-httponly-cookies)